# Move item in list with sorted numeric-index

Tags: database, algorithm, sorting

**Case:** Consider a list stored in sql-database with 2 columns:

```
-----------------------
Note      | Index_Value
-----------------------
Yellow    | 4
Red       | 7
Blue      | 3
Grey      | 30
```

The user is shown data of this list by simply sorting on `Index_Value` column, which is shown as:

```
Blue
Yellow
Red
Grey
```

**How** do I move `Grey` between `Red` & `Blue`, without affecting any other row but `Grey`'s index value?

I have came up with simple maths, but it's far from perfect.
**Solution:** Median of values between which object is moved
`( Index_Value(Previous) + Index_Value(After) )/2`
`(7 + 3)/2 = 5.5`
This approach produces large decimal numbers just after few repetitions.

Comment: why this approach produces large decimal numbers? The new index you generate would never become large than the maximum Index_Value

Comment: Is this a one time occurrence or will you do that often?  For a one of, reindex based on the order you want, increment +1 for every value.  @Alireza, I think what he means is if he needs to put some value between 5.5 and 5.6, it comes 5.55.  Then 5.555, then ...  The more he moves, the more he has to split with small numbers.

Comment: @Nic3500 This can occur often. And you are right about 5.55, 5.555, 5.5555 and so on.... One workaround for ever increasing decimals is re-indexing the entire list soon as any value hits memory threshold, so in case of mysql, as this number reaches close to 64 digits, reindex the list. But maybe some better way to do this.